# Python REGEX, reformat a string

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to create a regex that will take a string and replace certain characters

1. Double or more spaces reduces to one space
2. The following chars will be replaced by a word: "#" -> "number, "@" -> "at"
3. Spaces will be replaced with "-", unless its at the end of the string
4. Contains only a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and: !@#$%&/,
5. Double or more "-" will reduce to one

```
"Hello, Wor--ld! 1$2@3-   " -> "hello-wor-ld-1-dollars-2-at-3"
```

My code:

```
name = "Hello, World! 1$2@3-   "

name = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+","-",name.lower())

print(name)
```

But it results in "hello-world-1-2-3-"

Comment: it becomes lowercase too ? Can you edit example with a `#` to ensure what it becomes ?

Comment: Your example doesn't follow your rules at all. What about "dollars" , the comma, the "-" between the elements at the end ... I was ready to answer, but your question is very incomplete regarding your example

Comment: It seems the `!@#$%&` should all correspond to some words. What is the full list? "*`#` -> `number`, `@` -> `at`, `$` -> `dollars`", and the rest? Please fix your test case.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that you may use as a basis to solve your issue:

```py
import re
name = "Hello, World! 1$2@3-   "
name = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9@#$&]+", "-", " ".join(name.lower().split()))
dct = {'#': 'number', '@': 'at', '$': 'dollars', '&': 'and'}
name = re.sub(r'[$@#]', lambda x: f"-{dct[x.group()]}-", name)
print(name.strip('-'))
# => hello-world-1-dollars-2-at-3
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/jO2yR9).

Notes:

- `" ".join(name.lower().split())` - removes leading/trailing whitespaces, shrinks multiple whitespaces to a single occurrence between words and splits with whitespace
- `re.sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9@#$&]+", "-", ...)` - replaces all one or more consecutive chars other than alphanumeric, `#`, `@`, `$` and `&` chars with a hyphen
- `re.sub(r'[$@#]', lambda x: f"-{dct[x.group()]}-", name)` - replaces specified special chars with words
- `name.strip('-')` removes leading/trailing hyphens.

Comment: How can I check for a pattern for example when having "$2" the output would be "2-dollars" instead of "dollars-2"? the combination of $ before a number

Comment: When I put for example "Fries for $2" it returns "fries-for2-dollars" instead of "fries-for-2-dollars" or for "Hello, World! 1$2@3-   " returns "hello-world-12-dollars-at-3" instead of "hello-world-1-dollars-2-at-3"

Comment: How will I go about making it return for "Fries for $2.99@" -> "fries-for-2-dollars-99-cents-at"?

Comment: If rearranged to:
name = re.sub(r'[$@#]', lambda x: f"-{dct[x.group()]}-", name)
name = re.sub(r"-*(\$)(\d+)-*", r"\2\1", name)
out put would be "hello-world-1-dollars-2-at-3"
but "fries-for-dollars-2" instead of "fries-for-2-dollars"

Comment: @Adele Please check [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/Ba23yy). Your expectations start to diverge, I think `1$2` means `1-2-dollars` and not `1-dollars-2`. Else, the format is irregular and cannot be solved with regex.